# three js how to impose a sprite as a texture on a sphere

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

function createlabel(icon,label,label2,label3,backgroundcolor,fontcolor,opacity,x0,y0,z0){

```
   $('#imglabelcontainer').append('<div class="imglabel" id="imglabel'+label+'" style="  background:'+backgroundcolor+';color:'+fontcolor+';"><img height="48px" width="48px" src="'+icon+'" /><div>'+label3+'</div><div>'+label2+'</div><div class="label'+label+'">'+label+'</div></div>');

   var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 4, 32, 32 );
   var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: backgroundcolor});
   var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   sphere.position.x = x0;
   sphere.position.y = y0;
   sphere.position.z = z0;
   scene.add( sphere );
   //created sprite
   html2canvas(document.getElementById('imglabel'+label)).then(canvas => {
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); //default return - canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
    var ballTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(data); //make img
    console.log(data);
    var ballMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: ballTexture, useScreenCoordinates: false} ); //, color: 0xff0000
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(ballMaterial);
    sprite.position.set( x0, y0, z0 + 4.5);
    sprite.scale.set(5, 5 ); // imageWidth, imageHeight
    scene.add( sprite );
   });
```

}

Comment: What revision of Three.js do you use?

Comment: <script src="lib/html2canvas.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/OrbitControls.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas(document.getElementById('imglabel' + label),{
            backgroundColor: null
        }).then(function (div) {}

in html2canvas added the backgroundcolor:null and in my css added style border:radius